# AWS lambda with multer-3S upload unsupported image file. but local server upload correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I tried to upload image to AWS S3. In my local environment(same code as production environment), image upload successfully to S3 and i can download this image.

But through lambda environment, upload to S3 well, but this image is unable to  download. this image even have a larger size than image that be uploaded through local server.

I use same IAM between both environment. here is untouchable image url(lambda uploded)

[can't be download image url](https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/elebooks-image/book-cover/images1536836465032.jpg)

and this is touchable image url

[can be download image url](https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/elebooks-image/book-cover/images1536836488878.jpg)

please help me.

ps, my s3 policy is here

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1536755128154",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1536755126539",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elebooks-image/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1536827281212",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elebooks-image"
    }
]
```

}

my server code

```
 export const bookCoverUploader = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: bookCoverBucket,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      let extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(
        null,
        path.basename(file.originalname, extension) + Date.now().toString() + extension
      );
    },
    acl: 'public-read-write'
  })
});
```

Comment: are you getting 200 response from s3 when uploading using lambda environment ?

Comment: Yes. even uploaded successfully. but I think it has some conetent type error or something....i don'k know well

Comment: if the image is larger, is it possible that you are saving a base64 encoded file through Lambda when you are intending to save a binary? If so, the file approx. 1/3 larger when using Lambda. I encountered this issue when sending file to Lambda via API Gateway.

Comment: @KMo Thank you for comment. I user multer-3s and didn't write code about any encode part. I will post my code in this post.

Comment: How are you invoking the lambda?

Comment: Invoking ths lambda has no any error.